# Disable Default Beep using Parent control handle

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have an annoying problem with custom winforms control.

I use a standard empty UserControl, which is hosted by a custom form.

When I press any key the windows default beep triggers.

I overidden KeyDown/KeyPress but seems the beep occurs before my control receives the event.

Code for creating the control is plain simple:

```
    public class GUITemplateTestNode : UserControl, IPluginEvaluate
{
    public GUITemplateTestNode()
    {
        //setup the gui
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void InitializeComponent()
    {

    }

    public void Evaluate(int SpreadMax)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't have access to the form code, since it's hosted in another application (Delphi), but I have access to the main form Handle.

If I create a simple standalone (pure winforms) application, beep doesn't occur.

Is there's a way to use this parent form HWND to disable beeping?

Comment: Have you tried to set the [`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx) property to `true` in the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event ? That should *eat* the message.

Comment: What control has the focus here?  A UserControl does not want the focus, it is a container for other controls.  Keystrokes are sent to the window with the focus so it may well be the Delphi code that's beeping at you to remind you that pressing a key doesn't do anything useful.  If your UserControl doesn't actually have any child controls then deriving from Control instead is the proper thing to do .

Comment: Ok wondering if I shall delete the question, since actually asked the main app developers and the bug was that they had a debug beep function on key down on the plugin form, that made me laugh for a bit :)))